# Java - How can I prefer IPv6?

Tags: java, ipv6

I want to get the content of http://en.wikipedia.org using `java.net.URL`'s `openConnection()` method.

I find that en.wikiepdia.org has both IPv4 and IPv6 address:

```
$ host en.wikipedia.org
en.wikipedia.org is an alias for wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org.
wikipedia-lb.wikimedia.org is an alias for wikipedia-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org.
wikipedia-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org has address 208.80.154.225
wikipedia-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org has IPv6 address 2620:0:861:ed1a::1
```

How can I access that site using IPv6 address?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true
```

This jvm argument will work.

Answer (score 5):

IPv6 in Java is transparent and automatic. Just provide an an IPv6 address and you'll be good to go. Also check that your jvm does NOT have the following set to true

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/index.html):

Comment: This is incorrect, at least in 2024 with Java 17. If a machine has both IPv4 and IPv6, then Java will prefer IPv4 by default unless the java.net.preferIPv6Addresses system property is set to true.

Comment: I reckon some stuff might have changed in the last **10 years** ago ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: No, it hasn't... that's the problem. IPv6 support came to Java in 2002, and in 2024, Java will still prefer IPv4 over IPv6 for DNS resolution.