# IPv6 only socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, ip-address, ipv6

Is it possible to create a socket in java that binds only to ipv6 addresses?

I want to know if I can have 2 sockets on a machine such that one binds to ipv4 addresses and the other binds to ipv6 addresses only. [Networking IPv6 User Guide for JDK/JRE 5.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/) explains how ipv6 works on a Java platform but doesn't say anything about ipv6 only sockets. Are they even possible? I can't set the global IPV6_V6ONLY property.

Comment: But by definition, there is not such a thing. I think - IPv6 is designed to backward compatible, ?

Comment: oops, wrong logic. I guess I mean... of course, IPV6 is *only*  IPV6

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - How can I prefer IPv6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314241/java-how-can-i-prefer-ipv6)

Comment: @Elias I understand these options. I want to know if I can have 2 sockets on the same machine and force them to bind to ipv4 and ipv6 addresses only?

Comment: I think that set both types at same time, one to each socket, is not possible using purely Java. The restriction is on the remote host. `InetAddress.getByName()` returns an `Inet4Address` or an `Inet6Address` instance based on `preferIPv4Stack` property and in the host's capabilities.

Comment: I don't see why not, but if you're using something as old as Java 1.5 I wouldn't swear to its behavior. Try updating Java to a current supported version and posting the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same - to have separate tcp sockets (IPv4 and IPv6) that listen at the same port number. The only solution that I found is to create a pair of sockets (IPv4 and IPv6) for each address at the host.

For sake of simplicity the following code is limited to listen on localhost only. It creates two `ServerSocket` instances. One of then is bound to IPv4 localhost and one of them is bound to IPv6 localhost.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DualSock implements Runnable {

    ServerSocket s;
    String ver;
    static final int port = 1234;

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
               Socket client = s.accept();
               System.out.println("Connection over " + ver + " from " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
               client.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e);
               System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public DualSock(ServerSocket s, String ver) {
       this.s = s;
       this.ver = ver;
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        InetAddress address4 = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        ServerSocket server4 = new ServerSocket(port, 5, address4);
        DualSock ip4app = new DualSock(server4, "IPv4");

        InetAddress address6 = InetAddress.getByName("::1");
        ServerSocket server6 = new ServerSocket(port, 5, address6);
        DualSock ip6app = new DualSock(server6, "IPv6");

        new Thread(ip4app).start();
        new Thread(ip6app).start();
    }
}
```

It is not very useful to limit communication to localhost. A real application needs [enumerate network interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494465/how-to-enumerate-ip-addresses-of-all-enabled-nic-cards-from-java), get their addresses and then create a `ServerSocket` for each address at the host.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about IPV6 , is that is  only compatible with IPV6 .

[Which is the drawback of IPv6](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.networkworld.com%2Farticle%2F2265836%2Flan-wan%2Fbiggest-mistake-for-ipv6--it-s-not-backwards-compatible--developers-admit.html&ei=FmV_VN6zGIeeyATZ1YCABw&usg=AFQjCNEpRB-25ABceSAmosurmBI_szJ07A&sig2=A0KldRUnf_Lq8QRsORIMAg&bvm=bv.80642063,d.aWw)

As of 2014:

> IPv4, which still carries more than 96% of Internet traffic worldwide

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "compatible". There's lots of automatic transition-helpers.