# HttpURLConnection and INetAddress using hostname fails while IPv6 works fine

Tags: java, network-programming, httpurlconnection, ipv6, hostname

so initially, i wanted to access a file via HTTP GET using a URL like "http://myhostname:123/path/to/file". My Browser could access it without any problems, so the next step was to get it out of java code.

```
    URL url = new URL("http","myhostname",123,"path/to/file");
    URLConnection openConnection = url.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection asHttp = (HttpURLConnection) openConnection;
    assertEquals(200, asHttp.getResponseCode());
```

Sadly, I was running into a timeout. I was sniffing with Wireshark and couldn't see the request going over the wire.

Then i tried the exact same URL with IPv6 address and i could see the request going over the wire, but the server answered with HTTP 400 because he didn't liked not seeing "myhostname" written into the header.

`InetAddress.getByName("myhostname").isReachable(5000)` wasn't working as well, but works with IPv6.
When using the ping command on cmd.exe, i can successfully ping with "ping myhostname". I've got some C#-code which runs also fine when using "myhostname". *But why is it not working in Java and what do i need to do to make it functioning?*

Note: The host i want to get access to is a virtual machine running on my pc. Since i'm not experienced in network programming it could be a simple thing that i am missing.

Comment: If you run `ping myhostname`, does it ping IPv4 or IPv6? I'll assume IPv6, so running `ping -6 myhostname` would give same result. If you then run `ping -4 myhostname`, does it correctly ping IPv4?

Comment: If your DNS returns both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, but the IPv4 address doesn't work, fix the DNS, because Java will *by default* use the IPv4 address. Browsers and C# programs probably use the IPv6 address by default. It shouldn't matter which one you use, because if DNS returns both, they should both work. *Workaround:* Tell Java to use IPv6 address. See: [Java - How can I prefer IPv6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19314241/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas  Yes, `ping myhostname` pings IPv6. I already failed with trying `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "true");` ... i'm not quite sure if it was still the timeout or a different exception. I recheck that later. I just read that there is a "bullet-proof"-version with using jvm-arguments, have to check that as well. Nevertheless that would be a workaround - as you said - so fixing the DNS - however that works - seems to be in my focus for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i could solve my problem:

As @Andreas suggested i tried `ping -4 myhostname` and an IPv4 address was resolved, but the ping timed out.
I solved the problem by editing the host-file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and added the line `1234::1234:1234:1234:1234%2  myhostname`. I recheckd with `ping -4 myhostname` but now it didn't resolved an address while `ping myhostname` works fine using IPv6. My Java Code was running perfectly right away.

I also retried using `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "true");` and it worked out of a simple main()-method, but it wasn't working out of a JUnit-Test.