# JavaFX WebView and proper IPv6 use

Tags: java, javafx, webview, ipv6, ipv4

When going to the website test-ipv6.com on my normal browser, everything works fine. However, when I use JavaFX WebView to go to test-ipv6.com [I get this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W0F0.png)

This is what it says in [more info]:

> "First of all, we detected you had a working IPv6 connection. We also
> found that your IPv6 connection, was using a "real" IPv6 address;
> meaning not a Teredo or a 6to4 address.
> Second, we detected that when given the choice, **your browser decided
> it would prefer to use IPv4 instead of IPv6**. This has some concerns
> for us."

How can I make JavaFX WebView properly use IPv6? Or if not possible, what is an alternative web browser on Java that uses IPv6 properly?

EDIT: When disabling IPv4 from my computer entirely, WebView refuses to load anything entirely even though it seems like it has the ability to use IPv6 instead.

Answer (score 2):

I found this post which answered my question.  [Java - How can I prefer IPv6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314241/java-how-can-i-prefer-ipv6)

Setting this in the JVM arguments fixes it.

> -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true